# How to use Explode in my case?

Tags: php

I have a variable that contains text with values according to an example below:

```
$data = "5:7|4:1|504:2|1:3|"
```

And I would like to achieve results like this:

```
$data[5] = 7;
$data[4] = 1;
$data[504] = 2;
$data[1] = 3;
```

I tried with explode:

```
$data = explode("|", $data);

//but it makes $data[0]="5:7"; $data[1]="4:1"; and so on.
```

Should I use explode again? Is it has any sense, or is there another way? I would like to ask for a hint or help.

Comment: It will have the sense...you have to use the `explode` func 2 times in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a more clever way, but I'd do it like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach (explode("|", $your_data) as $part)
{
    $pieces = explode(':', $part);
    // Assumes we have 2 pieces, might want to make sure here...

    $data[$pieces[0]] = $pieces[1];
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what this data represents but keep in mind that array keys will overwrite each other, so `1:1|1:2` will result in an array with only one item (the last piece). There may be good reason to take another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `explode` again:

```
$data = "5:7|4:1|504:2|1:3";
$array = array();
foreach (explode('|', $data) as $pair) {
    list($id, $val) = explode(':', $pair);
    $array[$id] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use explode twice, like this

```
$newData = array();
$pairs = explode('|',$data);
foreach($pairs as $pair){
   $tmp = explode(':',$pair);
   $newData[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regexp:

```
$data = preg_split ("\||:", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

One line version:

```
$data = array_map(function($d) { return (int)explode(":", $d)[1]; }, explode("|", $data));
```